# Blocked - Good Question: Could a learner be encouraged by Educators here?

Tags: discussion, support

What does the following phrase mean? To encourage members to learn? I fail to understand how being blocked to ask questions might encourage a non-native speaker to learn here.

What is a good question? What is a useful question?  Are the Educators really here to help?

> Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.
>   For help formulating a clear, useful question, see: How do I ask a good question?
>   Also, edit your previous questions to improve formatting and clarity.

Comment: Blocking will encourage you to learn how to ask better and more useful questions.

Comment: There are lots of questions that are off-topic for this site, or otherwise inappropriate. This warning is meant to let you know that if the quality of your questions doesn't improve, you won't be allowed to ask any more questions. The primary function of that feature is to prevent people from abusing the system.

Comment: Please see [this FAQ posting and its answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997).

Answer (score 9):

You have 21 questions on your profile. 12 of them are scored zero or lower, which means the community judged those questions to be lacking quality for the site. Of the 9 questions you have with positive votes, 4 of them have been closed, which indicates that there are serious problems with the question.

Reasons a question gets negative votes: Poor grammar, questions that aren't clear or don't make sense, questions that are off-topic for the site, etc.

Reasons a question gets closed: being off-topic, or if the question can be answered by opening up a dictionary, or if the question has been asked before, or if the question cannot be answered for a variety of reasons, such as it not being clear what you're asking, or it being too opinion-based.

**You can help fix this by editing your questions to make them clearer, and deleting questions which are off-topic for the site.**

Also, if you're having trouble with more basic issues, you might want to consider [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/), our sister site that deals with more basic English questions.